# New flutter builds not compliing anymore after trying to install firebase

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart

recently i have been trying to install firebase on my flutter with no sucesss so i gave up, but now even when i create a brand new flutter project in vsCode it wont run even once giving me the error:

Unhandled exception:
Crash when compiling file:///Users/Documents/FlutterDevelopment/SDKS/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/app.dart at character offset 71686:
../…/widgets/app.dart:1
type 'Null' is not a subtype of type 'Procedure' in type cast

its doing this on new builds and old ones that worked before.

I was expecting a brand new project to run as it always has.

Comment: Have you tried running `flutter clean`?

Answer (score 0):

The attempt to download firebase unsuccesfully messed up my flutter sdk so i simply downloaded a fresh one and replaced the old one.